# asmx service should retrieve more then 2000 items

Tags: asmx

I want to retrieve big amount of items from my asmx service. Everything works fine, but when I am trying to retrieve more then 2000 items I get 500 error. I figured out that I should fix some config settings. Help) please. my config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <configuration>
    <system.web>
    <compilation batch="false" batchTimeout="6000" maxBatchSize="100000"   maxBatchGeneratedFileSize="100000" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory, System.Web, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=..." />
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <customErrors mode="On" />
    <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" />
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="36000" maxRequestLength="20480" />
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet" />
        <add name="HttpPost" />
        <remove name="HttpPostLocalhost" />
        <add name="Documentation" />
      </protocols>
     </webServices>
    </system.web>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: can you put some code please, 500 means internal server error, you can try enabling logging on the server side, also try putting the server code in a try-catch and see what exception is being thrown

Comment: How large are the items being returned? ASMX does not use memory efficiently. The response may be copied three or more times. You could be running out of memory if it's large.

Comment: I have collection of objects. Every object has 4 field (2 string and 2 bool)count of the collection is 2600 objects. Is it big?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem, when you need to return large data to users, there are several considerations here:

- user doesn't need that much data you want to return
- user rather get small result quickly then  wait for ages whilst the whole chunk of data is received
- your server has many users and limited amount of RAM

Thus

- Limit data that is requested and adopt [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging)
- Make small queries with lazy load
- Use compression like GZIP
- Take a look at [Large Data and Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx)
- Move to WCF as ASMX web services is an outdated technology